# Laravel 5.8 Passport "resulted in a `401 Unauthorized`"

Tags: php, laravel

I have an issue with my laravel 5.8 project..

I want to make registration and get tokens using passport with Guzzle but when i post a new record to get token, i get error saying

```
"`POST http://femlife.test/oauth/token` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:
{"error":"invalid_credentials","error_description":"The user credentials were incorrect.","message":"The user credential (truncated...)"
```

Here is my code:

$http = new Client;

```
    $response = $http->post('http://femlife.test/oauth/token', [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => 2,
            'client_secret' => 'gpnQCoxmAxeiW8srk50j5onLiwvRs3dc8aiID3S3',
            'username' => $request->name,
            'password' => $request->password,
            'scope' => '',
            'code' => 200,
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost'
        ],
    ]);

    return response(['data'=>json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true)]);
```

Please, What am i doing wrong? I saw some suggestions that i have to separate Server and Client instances because now,am using one XAMPP instance..

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in this line:

```
'username' => $request->name,
```

You may set username with wrong value. make sure that your username field name is correct.

Comment: Seems not working! I even replaced $request->name with a string which should have worked... But not!